# How to use `--execution` and `--wasm-execution` when setting up a node?

Tags: wasm

I want to know the design relationship between them.

From the node binary help:

```
--execution <STRATEGY>
            The execution strategy that should be used by all execution contexts [possible values: Native,
            Wasm, Both, NativeElseWasm]

--wasm-execution <METHOD>
            Method for executing Wasm runtime code [default: Compiled]  [possible values: interpreted-i-know-
            what-i-do, compiled]
```

1. If both of them are not configured, the default `execution` is `NativeElseWasm` and the default `--wasm-execution` is `compiled`?
2. If I add `--execution=native`, which means the `wasm-execution` is also set to `Compiled`, is there no need to configure it explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `--execution` you configure what kind of execution will be used. As you already have seen you can configure stuff like `NativeElseWasm` or `Wasm` or `NativeThenWasm` etc. This just configures which kind of runtime you will execute. There is the native runtime and the wasm runtime. The native runtime is compiled natively into the node and brings some better performance than the wasm runtime. However, when you upgrade the runtime on chain you always send the wasm runtime. The wasm runtime is the canonical one. If there is a new runtime enacted on chain, your node is running with `NativeElseWasm` and it doesn't support this new runtime yet, your node will fallback to use the wasm runtime.

Regarding `--wasm-execution`, this controls how the wasm runtime is executed. `Compiled` means you will use a wasm compiler that brings better performance than using an interpreter (the other option). However, the interpreter is also discouraged to use, because it is too slow.

> If both of them not config, the default execution is `NativeElseWasm` and the default `--wasm-execution` is compiled?

Yes.

> If add --execution=native, which means the wasm-execution is also set to Compiled, so no need to config explicitly?

`wasm-execution` is by default `Compiled` when the wasm compiler is enabled at compile time.

Comment: Another question: Why keep the `wasm-execution=interpreter` option? From the explanation, if there is only one option(Compiled) for `wasm-execution`, then no need to keep `wasm-execution` arg, it's would be much easier to use.

Comment: Yeah that may come in the future. I mean, you already don't need to specify `--wasm-execution`, because the best value is chosen for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of good information about these flags and the underlying executor in the documentation here: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/executor/

To answer your questions:

1. The default execution strategy for different contexts are different:

   - Syncing: `NativeElseWasm`
   - Block Import (for non-validator): `NativeElseWasm`
   - Block Import (for validator): `AlwaysWasm`
   - Block Construction: `AlwaysWasm`
   - Off-Chain Worker: `NativeWhenPossible`
   - Other: `NativeWhenPossible`
2. If you set `--execution=native` then I don't think it really matters what `--wasm-execution` is set to since you will be using a native executor rather than a Wasm executor, but yes, will set to `compiled` by default.